# SQL Server: lock only one row and update it in concurrence access

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please help me in the following case.

I have a table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

and I inserted two rows: (id = 1, value = 10), (id = 2, value = 20)

Then I did the following steps:

In one SSMS connection I run a procedure what should lock and update only one row

```
BEGIN TRAN;

DECLARE @Value INT;

SELECT @Value = Value
FROM Table1 with (HOLDLOCK XLOCK ROWLOCK)
WHERE Id = 1;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:20';

UPDATE Table1 
SET Value = @Value + 5
WHERE Id = 1;

COMMIT TRAN;

SELECT Value 
FROM Table1
WHERE Id = 1
```

And right after that I run another SSMS connection transaction

```
SELECT [Id], [Value]
FROM [dbo].[Table1]
WHERE Id = 2
```

And I observe that the second connection freezes and waits until the first transaction is about to end.

I can't understand why the second transaction waits for the first. The first transaction locks row with id=1 and second selects just one row with id=2. It seems to me that the first transaction acts like I used a `TABLOCKX` hint.

Could someone explain this, or give an advise? Thanks!

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? And what is the default transaction isolation level in your database you're using here? With SQL Server 2017 (Developer Ed) - this works just fine - session #1 updated and locks row id=1, while selecting row with id=2 works just fine...

Comment: Is there a key on the table?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: good catch! When I test this with a table *without* proper primary key, I see the same behavior as the OP - **yet another** compelling reason to have a  **primary key** on every table ever ! :-)

Comment: I use MS Sql Server 13.0.1601.5. Transaction isolation level i use default (Read Committed). And after i created key for ID column, all works fine (with XLOCK ROWLOCK hints for both transactions)      Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After applying

```
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

all works fine with following transaction

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[Value]
  FROM [dbo].[Table1] with (XLOCK, ROWLOCK)
  where Id = 1
GO
```

and

```
BEGIN TRAN;

DECLARE @Value INT;

SELECT @Value = Value
--FROM Table1 with (HOLDLOCK XLOCK ROWLOCK)
FROM Table1 with (XLOCK ROWLOCK)
WHERE Id = 1;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';

UPDATE Table1 
SET Value = @Value + 5
WHERE Id = 1;

COMMIT TRAN;

SELECT Value 
FROM Table1
WHERE Id = 1;
```

Thanks!